# Android: Images button layout vertically that will fit all screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I'm having problems with my layout I want to arrange the image buttons vertically and I want it to have the same look for different screen sizes here is a print screen http://flic.kr/p/fwEZn1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/chalk"
android:gravity="center|fill_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="1000dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/m"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.30"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="exam schedule button"
        android:onClick="ex"
        android:src="@drawable/exam" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="classes button"
        android:onClick="cl"
        android:src="@drawable/list1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lec"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.24"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="lecture section button"
        android:onClick="lc"
        android:src="@drawable/sylla" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.36"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="group button"
        android:onClick="gr"
        android:src="@drawable/group" />
      </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
  android:layout_width="1000dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
  android:layout_marginTop="123dp" >

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/kl"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="74dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.69"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:contentDescription="calendar button"
      android:onClick="kl"
      android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

     <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/d"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pd"
      android:layout_marginRight="84dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.38"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:contentDescription="Schedule button"
      android:onClick="sk"
      android:src="@drawable/sked" />

     <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/pd"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/an"
      android:layout_weight="0.16"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:contentDescription="podcast button"
      android:onClick="pd"
      android:src="@drawable/podcast" />

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/an"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/kl"
      android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kl"
      android:layout_weight=".92"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:contentDescription="announcement button"
      android:onClick="an"
      android:src="@drawable/announce" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="53dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="342dp"
  android:layout_weight="0.38"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:contentDescription="logout button"
  android:onClick="logout"
  android:src="@drawable/logout"
  android:text="Logout" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

So basically I want to fix the arrangement of the images button. How can I do this? Do I need to resize images per drawable folder?

Answer (score 0):

Did You mean the same Size for all screen sizes when You say "look"? A possible way to do this, would be to set to ImageButton in Your xml:

```
    scaleType="centerInside"
```

and set all weights from Your image buttons to 1

```
    layout_weight="1"
```

And if You want to set every button vertical, declare in Your LinearLayout

```
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

And by the way, it is allways a good practise to set different images for every drawable to fit in multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. I see you want the layout to look the same in all screen sizes, but you are using hard coded values for layout_height,margin,padding etc. For this purpose use the dimens.xml in the values folder. Specify the values for all screens, create these folders in your resource folder:

```
   values-small
   values-normal(The default values folder is values-normal)       
   values-large
   values-xlarge(You can use values-sw600 for tablets after Android 3.2)
```

In all of these folders create dimens.xml where you specify the margin,height,width,padding etc in dp, you can even specify the font size. Hope this helps!